# C# API POST with user/pass + datas , and Get infos of this datas

Tags: c#, json, api, curl, post

I've read many topics and forums to help myself but I didnt find an issue

you can see my code here [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4IA5.jpg) and below

How can i add value in my **parameters** ( like an ID ) and get the response
With this code , i've got a "1.0.2 wrong parameter , please use it correctly "

if i use a ETL and i'm making it with a CURL call its ok , but i want to do it in C#

exemple of my curl parameters < **-d '{\"id\":[\"123456\"]}'** >

I tryed to add "id" in my bye[]data = ..... (postData + id) 
where id = [123456] or {[123456]} or &[123456] or :[123456]

I have no idee , someone can help me ? 
Thx

```
try
{
            // init data
            string user = "user1";
            string pass = "password1";
            string url = "https://mysite/getdatas/";

            // init lib
            ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            string postData = user + ":" + pass;

            byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(postData) ;

            // lib parameters 

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass);

            Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            stream.Close();

            // reponse > stream 
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();

            // display stream ( response )
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
            Console.ReadLine();
            sr.Close();
            stream.Close();
        }
```

Comment: It might help if you posted the code into the question rather than posting a link to a picture of your code (I'm assuming that's what it is anyway, I haven't actually clicked on the link).

Comment: Did it :) thx ( i used the picturebox of the site)

Comment: Your post data should be the same as what you use in Curl, not the username and password.

Comment: The problem is : How add it ? How add my datas ? How send with user + pass + datas , and get the infos of the datas ?

Comment: I don't know what API you are using or what it's requirements are, but it may be that all you need to do is : `string postData = "{\"id\":[\"123456\"]}";`.

Comment: I tryed its not working, but there may be missing one element between : 
user:pass&postdata - 
or - 
user:pass:postdata - 
Cause i need to have a ":" between user and pass

Comment: Not all API's work the same. You have to know what they expect for a request, I can only guess. Based on what I see it looks like the API uses Basic authentication which would mean the username and password go in an `Authorization` header, not in the post body. Typically that header will be base64 encoded. You really need to understand the basics of HTTP and also how that API works or you will just be throwing code at the problem, hoping something works.

Comment: url webService
Interface : REST
Methode : POST
UTF-8
JSON in/out
SYNC response
Header : application/json
HTTP DIGEST BASIC (login/password)

Comment: If you can capture your traffic with Fiddler while doing that CURL command you should get everything you need to be able to recreate the request in c#.

Answer (score 0):

I've examined the code you posted as a picture. As far as I understand, you want to make an API call to an existing web api. The following link could be helpful for that purpose.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

And I also prepared a small example for you, which includes an ASP.NET Web API and a console application which makes an API call.

Web API Side:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebAPICall.Controllers
{
    public class PeopleController : ApiController
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person> { new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John" }, new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Mary" } };

        // GET api/People/1
        public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            Person person = people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);

            if (person == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return Ok(person);
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Client Side:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApiTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunAsync().Wait();
        }

        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            // Before using, "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client"
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56409/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            Person person = null;
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/People/1");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                person = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Person>();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Id: {0}, Person: {1}", person.Id, person.Name);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I've tested the code above and it's working.
The output is:

```
Id: 1, Person: John
```

Please let me know if this is what you asked for.

Note: In order to use HttpClient, you need to install Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client via Nuget Package Manager in your client project.

Comment: I will read your response and thx to be so fast ! but its "SYNC Method" and i'm not working in Webforms, but in console C#

Comment: I dont understand why you add : api/people/1 in the url ?

Comment: And i get an error on person = HttpContent' ne contient pas de définition pour 'ReadAsAsync' et aucune méthode d'extension 'ReadAsAsync' acceptant un premier argument de type 'HttpContent' n'a été trouvée (une directive using ou une référence d'assembly est-elle manquante ?) RestApi

Comment: @anamax59, KodFun is showing you an example, not what exact code you should actually use. KodFun is making assumptions about what your API is but cannot know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I'm missing something like = ? % / in the array input

user:password?id=[123456]

user:password?%[123456]

and if I want many IDs , [123456,789] ...